# How can I make a responsive navbar that is fixed to the top of the screen

Tags: html, css, pug

I'm attempting to create a responsive navbar that is fixed at the top of the page, and with the links full height (100%) so that their background colors can change. I've so far only succeeded in making the navbar fixed, and the links are only somewhat compatible across devices. I'm going for this effect, where the media queries force the menu into a nav contained in an image. http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/. I dislike bootstrap, and I want to be able to do this on my own in the future. Any tips?

Here is the code I have:

Jade:

> head
>
> link(rel="stylesheet", href="/main.css")
>
> nav
>
> ```
> ul
>
>    li
>
>        a(href="/") Home
>
>        a(href="/about") About
>
>        a(href="/contact") Contact
> ```

and

LESS:

> nav {
>
> width:100%;
>
> height:3em;
>
> top:0px;
>
> left:0px;
>
> position:fixed;
>
> background-color:#000;
>
> ul li a {
>
> ```
>    height:100%;
>
>    text-align:center;
>
>    margin-top: -3.5em;
>
>    text-decoration:none;
>
>    padding-right: 9%;
>
>    padding-left: 9%;
>
>    &:hover {
>
>        color:#7f8c8d;
>
>    }
> ```
>
> }
>
> }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rethink the `fixed` positioning of your header and incorporate an `absolute` method instead. I personally don't like having a header constantly in my way, but the `absolute` can be changed to `fixed` easily with the below code.

Here is the way I would typically do it to ensure that everything will stay up top.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
<ul id="navBar">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    min-width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
}
#wrapper {
    background:#AAA;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
ul {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
li {
    float:left;
    min-width:50px;
    background:#CCC;
    list-style:none;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding:15px;
}
li a {  
    color:#000;
}
```

Or fiddle away yourself:

#### JS FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/d83H3/1/

---

#### EDIT:

Try this for your media query quarrels. You can resize the fiddle window. Try to reduce it to 300px or less for the bottom right preview window.

#### JS FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/d83H3/2/

Comment: Nicholas, thanks a ton. Do you know of a method where I can incorporate a media query effect such as the one shown on http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/?

Comment: So it turns into an icon rather than a menu at specified size?

Comment: Updated answer with media queries. (resize the fiddle window to 300px or smaller).

Comment: I'm not going to build the whole drop down menu for you, but if you include all of your CSS and whatnot targeting the ID I've laid out (namely `icon`) it will still hide when large and display when shrunk. Was that the question you were asking?

Comment: Thank you, yeah I would like to learn a bit on my own. Thanks a ton!